# Get real-time CMD command output in C# application

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I want to create a desktop application like command prompt. in that application, I get input from a textbox and put the real-time output on rich-textbox.

but some of commands need to wait for complete execute like "composer install" (that will downloading required resources that's why taking long time and it's also displaying process status of downloading in percentage)

So my main question is how can i do something like command prompt that can give dynamic output with light weight no hanging if any other language instead of c# can do that then suggest me.

my desktop application look like this.

[image]

and c# "Run" button on click event method is as following.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = "";
    if (textBox1.Text != null)
    {

        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + textBox1.Text);

        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.RedirectStandardError = true;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;

        StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder errorBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = info;
        process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);
        process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);

        process.Start();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine(); // do this after process.Start()
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();

        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}

private void SortOutputHandler(object sendingProcess,DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
    StringBuilder sortOutput = new StringBuilder("");
    if (richTextBox1.InvokeRequired) { richTextBox1.BeginInvoke(new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler), new[] { sendingProcess, outLine }); }
    else
    {
        sortOutput.Append(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
        richTextBox1.AppendText(sortOutput.ToString());
        richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
    }
}
```

my code is completely works but application is hanging until command is executed completely while run dynamic commands like "composer install"

Comment: you are waiting for the process to exit `process.WaitForExit();` which blocks the current thread of execution, you move the code to another thread

Comment: nothing happens after removes process.WaitForExit(); and the problem is when I run "tree \windows" command in it then it's take something 30 seconds to execute completely. in between that time, I can't do moving my application or retype my command or anything else, application hanging or stopping all user's events for a bit of second but output gives correct as expected while it's hanging.

Comment: as I said before you should move that long-running process into a different thread

Comment: Thanks, @styx for helping it's working good enough.